# JDOM 1.1: hyphen is not a valid comment character

Tags: java, web-crawler, jdom, tag-soup

I'm using tagsoup to clean some HTML I'm scraping from the internet, and I'm getting the following error when parsing through pages with comments:

```
The data "- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - " is not legal for a JDOM comment: Comment data cannot start with a hyphen.
```

I'm using JDOM 1.1, and here's the code that does the actual cleaning:

```
    SAXBuilder builder = new org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder("org.ccil.cowan.tagsoup.Parser"); // build
    // Don't check the doctype! At our usage rate, we'll get 503 responses
    // from the w3.
    builder.setEntityResolver(dummyEntityResolver);
    Reader in = new StringReader(str);
    org.jdom.Document doc = builder.build(in);
    String cleanXmlDoc = new org.jdom.output.XMLOutputter().outputString(doc);
```

Any idea what's going wrong, or how to fix this? I need to be able to parse pages with long comment strings of `<!--------- data ------------>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An [XML/HTML/SGML comment](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/wilbur/misc/comment.html) begins with `--`, ends with `--` and does not contain `--`. A comment declaration contains zero or more comments.

Your example string can be reformatted as:

```
<!----
  ----
  - data
  ----
  ----
  ---->
```

As you can see, `- data` is not a valid comment and therefore the document is not valid HTML. In your specific case you can probably fix it by replacing the regular expression `/<?!--.*?-->/` with the empty string, but be aware that this change might also break some valid documents.

Comment: Given this, is there a way for tagsoup to swallow comments entirely? I do not need the comment data, and it is preventing me from parsing pages correctly. Fixing the HTML page should be a part of the library, I think, and if I can make tagsoup do this, all the better.

Comment: @Stefan Kendall: I'm not sure it's possible for a generic library to fix this kind of error in general. Consider for example: `<!------ foo ----><b>data</b><!---- bar ------>`. This is a valid comment declaration but it probably doesn't do what you expect. It consists of the following comments: `<empty>`, ` foo `, `><b>data</b><!`, ` bar `, `<empty>`. If you remove comments, you will also remove the data. In other cases where the comment declaration is invalid, it is not clear what should happen.

Comment: Ack, this is still a yucky situation. By manually scrubbing the data before sending it to tagsoup, I was able to get around the problem. The pages I'm scraping are pretty cookie-cutter, so I knew I could make the change without worrying about edge cases.